# SSRS Report expands table width on page 4 only on PDF

Tags: pdf, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

My report is doing this:

[image: Table Width Changed Image]

This only happens when I export the report to PDF.  HTML view looks just fine...

I am not sure where to even start.  The first 3 pages are perfect.  It is just page 4 that gets messed up.

Any guesses of where I should look to fix this are welcome.

Comment: Do pages 1-3 have text in the expected result column?  From what you've posted that's the only difference I can see.

Comment: @lazyDBA - Yes they do, though my image does not show it.  They have more or less what you see in the 4th page.

Comment: The parameter and values rows are all hidden on the 4th page.  So the format got messed up.  If one of those rows is shown then the formatting works....  This is smelling like a bug in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this same thing in SSRS 2008 and it was extremely frustrating; it was definitely a weird bug of some kind and not just a page-overlap kind of thing (I turned on borders, and made sure none of the cells weren't meant to expand).

From memory, recreating the tablix from scratch made it go away. Although, around the same time I was updating to 2008 SP2 so you might want to check what revision of service pack you're on, too.